# How/When is CRX and Apache Jackrabbit used in CQ5/AEM?

Tags: aem, jackrabbit, crx

Lately, I have spent some time trying to better understand the AEM technology stack.  There are so many pieces, it seems easy to get confused.  I have been looking over the JCR implementations on AEM.  I keep reading that it uses CRX.  However, I know that it uses Apache Jackrabbit as well.  Is it using both?  What is the logic behind using both implementations?  When and where is each used?

A better question might be what is the relationship between CRX and Jackrabbit?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**JCR** (JSR-170) is the a standard Java **API** for content repositories.  It provides an interface for Java applications to interact with content repositories, however it does *not* provide a *repository implementation*.

Apache **[Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/)** is an **open source** content repository **[implementation](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr-api.html)** that fully implements the JCR API.

Adobe **CRX** is the commercial content repository component used in the AEM, which uses some elements of Jackrabbit (e.g. some of the [security APIs](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.4/org/apache/jackrabbit/api/security/user/package-summary.html)).  CRX provides additional features such as [development tools](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/developing/development_tools/developing_with_crxde.html) & [clustering capabilities](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/administering/cluster.html) and has its own [storage mechanism](http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2008/11/tarpm.html) which differs from the Jackrabbit implementation.

Comment: Looking at the Day CRX API bundle in the Felix Console, it shows that Jackrabbit is imported by it.  From what I understand (correct me if I am wrong), CRX is just Jackrabbit with additional features provided alongside it?

Comment: It certainly uses bits of Jackrabbit (e.g. [UserManager](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.0/org/apache/jackrabbit/api/security/user/UserManager.html)).  It replaces bits (like the  persistence mechanism) and also adds things which aren't a part of Jackrabbit (e.g CRXDE).

Comment: Besides its extra tools, it feels like it is a forked version of jackrabbit.

Comment: Adobe form a large part of [the team](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jackrabbit-team.html) that work on Jackrabbit.  It's actively developed as a key component of CRX, but there is some stuff that they keep behind for their commerical offering.  When the [Jackrabbit Oak] (http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/) project (that implements an alternative storage mechanism) comes to fruition, I expect that this will be adopted by CRX.

Comment: @Woodifer CRX is not actually forked. It really _is_ just Jackrabbit, with some pieces replaced and other pieces added (mainly tools), just like diffa wrote. (I'm one of the developers of Jackrabbit and CRX.)

Answer (score 3):

CRX is commercial implementation of Apache Jackrabbit with features like :

- TarPM
- List item
- Shared Nothing Clustering
- LDAP Integration
- Content Package Management

Shared Nothing Clustering 3/ LDAP Integration 4/ Content
   Package Management

Refer following in adobe [forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/994232)